# Pywikibot Login SSLError 185090050

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, pywikibot

Previously I had no problem with Pywikibot library and `site.login()`.

From last week, calling this method returns the following warning and error messages:

```
WARNING: Waiting 40 seconds before retrying.
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pywikibot/data/api.py", line 1556, in submit
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "pywikibot/tools/__init__.py", line 1105, in wrapper
    return obj(*__args, **__kw)
  File "pywikibot/comms/http.py", line 279, in request
    r = fetch(baseuri, method, body, headers, **kwargs)
  File "pywikibot/comms/http.py", line 381, in fetch
    error_handling_callback(request)
  File "pywikibot/comms/http.py", line 297, in error_handling_callback
    raise request.data
SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:340: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An expert at http://webchat.freenode.net/#pywikibot solved the problem.

The problem was with my httplib2 package. I simply reinstalled it using:

```
pip uninstall httplib2
pip install httplib2
```